# How can I reorder rows GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, grid, devexpress

My gridview has a list, and the record's list have priorities. I need to click and drag rows to modify the priorities. For example:

```
Register 1  - Priority 1 

Register 2  - Priority 2  

Register 3  - Priority 3
```

If I click and drag the row of Register 1 to last row, it must be:

```
Register 3 - Priority 1 

Register 2 - Priority 2

Register 1 - Priority 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not understand if your problem is with a gridview or an ASPxGridview.

If you are using a devexpress grid view (for example in a winform) you could apply a solution like that https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E764 where the row Order is you field Priority.

If you are using an ASPxGridview in a web application the scenario is a bit more complex,but i suppose you can follow this tutorial https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4582

Comment: I am using ASPxGridView and I am also using MVC. This example is using WebForms.